# Custom Order in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I need to order transaction based on the currency.
However I need to implement a custom order by, which makes the USD to always comes on the top, and the rest should be ordered asc.

for example :

- BHT
- USD
- MYR
- JYP

should be sorted like :

- USD
- BHT
- JPY
- MYR

Is there a simple way to handle this?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Don't know if this qualifies as simple:

```
order by 
    case 
       when currency = 'USD' then 1 
       when currency = 'BHT' then 2
       when currency = 'JPY' then 3
       when currency = 'MYR' then 4
       else 5
    end
```

or a bit more compact but Oracle specific:

```
order by decode(currency, 'USD', 1, 'BHT', 2, 'JPY', 3, 'MYR', 4, 5)
```

The above solution using numbers to defined the sort order will not automatically sort currencies correctly that aren't mentioned in the case/decode expression.

To simply put USD at the front and don't care about the rest, the "generated" order criteria must be a character value as well. You can use the following in that case:

```
order by 
    case 
       when currency = 'USD' then '001' 
       else currency
    end
```

Which uses an "alphabetical" ordering. This works because characters are sorted after the number digits. (Using `'AAA'` instead of `'001'` would work as well).

Comment: OP took 4 countries for example purpose. I don't think above is the right way... Its like doing it manually... What If I add country as ARG? Will you change your query again?

Comment: @FahimParkar: that's why I added the solution using character ordering. That will put USD at the top and everything else alphabetically (I removed the hardcoded currencies in the second solution).

Comment: hmm, second one is nice solution. +1 for that :)

Comment: This is nice, thanks! Is there a way i can also filter in my where clause via some kind of new ordering? Like where this field is < that field via my numbering?

Comment: Is decode slower than that of the case? Over 1 million records?

Answer (score 24):

To make sure Your sort is "flexible" and will work with all currencies do this:

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM <tableName>
ORDER BY DECODE(currencyColumn,'USD', 1, 2), currencyColumn
```

Answer (score 10):

A more detailed way of doing this, if you are interesting in sorting certain values to the beginning or end, but have those sorted in their group:

```
order by
  case when currency in ('USD', 'CAD') 
    then '000'||currency
  when currency in ('ZWD', 'HTG')
    then 'ZZZ'||currency
  else currency 
  end
```

This will put the USD and CAD at the top of the list (sorted), ZWD and HTG at the bottom, and the rest sorted between those.

Comment: Great Answer! Helped me avoid doing a "Union". Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
order by decode(currency, 'USD', 1, 2)
```

or using `case`

```
  order by 
      case 
        when currency = 'USD' then 1 
        else 2
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

One more variant with regexp like function `FIELD()` in MySQL:

```
select
meas_code,
to_number(regexp_replace(meas_code, replace('(meas1,meas2,meas3)', ',', '|'), instr(replace('(meas1,meas2,meas3)', ',', '|'), meas_code))) ordr
from (select cast(column_value as varchar2(10)) as meas_code from xmltable('''meas1'',''meas2'',''meas3'''))
order by 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom order i suggest you to use 'FIELD'.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(column,"case 1","case 2",...);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do the following:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  yourtable
ORDER BY
  REPLACE(FIND_IN_SET(currency,'USD,BHT,JPY,MYR'),0,'Z')
```

Answer (score -1):

I needed to do the same, but with multiple columns, and found Grzegorz W's answer the best for this, with the following simple addition:

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM <tableName>
ORDER BY DECODE(currencyColumn,'USD', 1, 2), currencyColumn, anotherColumn;
```

Comment: Whoever down voted this want to explain why? If my code doesn't match my text, then sure, down vote and explain why you think it is wrong. If not, then really?! Sure, my answer doesn't exactly match the OP's question, but I came across this thread when searching the answer to my problem, and Grzegorz W's answer best matched my problem. So I reposted my exact solution for the next person's benefit who is looking for the same answer as me. This, in my view, is the wonderful thing about stackoverflow. I have found many solutions to my problems from posts just like mine.

Comment: Probably downvoted (not by me) because you've added **anotherColumn** but have not explained what it is or why you'd need to do this. If I posted the exact same answer as you and included **yetAnotherColumn** I'd expect a downvote.