# Get results in order of values passed in 'IN' oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have

```
SELECT * FROM adp_relations WHERE rel_name IN ('primary2bus_org', 'employee2user')
```

I want to select and return the records with the specified order which i pass in the IN clause (first display record with primary2bus_org='xyz', employee2user='abc', ...)

What is the efficient way to do this?

Comment: Try using CASE statement for [ORDER BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339589/custom-order-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: Awesome it worked, and nice method.

Comment: Glad to know that it has helped.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use derived table:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 'primary2bus_org' AS rel_name, 1 AS orderNum FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'employee2user' AS rel_name, 2 AS orderNum FROM dual
)
SELECT a.* 
FROM adp_relations a
JOIN cte c
  ON a.rel_name = c.rel_name
ORDER BY c.orderNum;
```

Please note that if your `adp_relations` has multiple occurences of any searched string, the order of each "subgroup" will be nondereministic(or rather exectution plan dependent):

```
1 primary2bus_org
2 primary2bus_org
3 primary2bus_org
10 employee2user

vs

3 primary2bus_org
2 primary2bus_org
1 primary2bus_org
10 employee2user
```

If so you should add `ORDER BY c.orderNum, a.<col_which_is_unique_like_id>` to get stable sort.