# I need to do a Custom Oracle Sort

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I'm sorry if this is a simple question. However, I have searched high and low for the answer over about an hour.

I have a db_table with that I need to sort for output to a table in a webpage. The data is stored in the db_table in the following way:

```
   date          Area         Value
   ------        ------      -------
 11-mar-18        middle        10
 11-mar-18        bottom         5
 11-mar-18        top           12

 12-mar-18        top           14
 12-mar-18        bottom         4
 12-mar-18        middle        17
```

The question is: how can I sort these to produce the following result:

```
    date          Area         Value
   ------        ------      -------
 11-mar-18        top           12 
 11-mar-18        middle        10
 11-mar-18        bottom         5 

 12-mar-18        top           14
 12-mar-18        middle        17
 12-mar-18        bottom         4
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
  from db_table
 order by "date", 
    case 
       when area = 'top' then 1 
       when area = 'middle' then 2
       when area = 'bottom' then 3
       else 4
    end;
```

Refer to [Custom Sort Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339589/custom-order-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: "Simple" case expression works even better: `case area when 'top' then 1 when 'middle' then 2 when 'bottom' then 3 end` Also note that if you leave out `else 4`, the default is `else null` - with the same effect on ordering. You don't really need the `else` part.

Comment: @mathguy, without `else 4`, areas that are null or of values other than top, middle or bottom will appear first.  May be that is fine.  `else 4` put them at the end of each group.  The OP has to make that decision.

Comment: No. Without `else 4`, the `case` expression will return `null` for rows other than top, middle or bottom, and `null` appears last (by default - if not explicitly requested to appear first) in `order by`. You seem unfamiliar with this, so it will help you to write a very small example for yourself, and run it. You will see what I mean.

Comment: @mathguy you are right. I was testing in mysql not oracle.

Comment: What is different in MySQL? The "else null" default for `case` and the "nulls last" default for ordering are both in the SQL Standard.

Answer (score 6):

Sort area descending alphabetically as the second component of *order by* :

```
select *
  from db_table
 order by "date", area desc;
```

As you mentioned if area has values A,B,C,D and they wanted to be sorted in the order of C,B,D,A, then use :

```
select *
  from db_table
 order by "date", decode(area,'C',1,'B',2,'D',3,'A',4);
```

P.S. especially, i put date column inside quotes, since already created table with `"date"` column, instead of `date` which is impossible as being a keyword.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention one aspect. What if the options in the area column were A,B,C,D for example and I wanted to sort by date then sort the areas as C,B,D,A?

Comment: order by "date", decode(area,'C',1,'B',2,'D',3,'A',4)

Comment: Best to use `decode` (or `case`) in all situations, and not exploit the accident that TOP, MIDDLE and BOTTOM happen to be in reverse lexicographic order. One day they will change to FIRST, MIDDLE, LAST and the query won't give the correct order anymore. Best to force them to make the needed changes to `ORDER BY`, if they ever do something like that.

Answer (score 4):

`instr()` provides a shorter solution than `case` in most cases:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.date, instr('top,middle,bottom', area)
```

Comment: Ugh...  What if the values to order by, in this order, are stop, top, and op? No serious programmer should ever use tricks like this. Use `decode` if you find `case` too verbose.

Comment: @mathguy . . . The values are fixed.  This is a perfectly reasonable solution in most cases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks, this helps me when sorting sizes, I used INSTR('XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL', size_cd, 1) and it works. This trick is really helpful in my end.