# Select values from database based on the same order of values in IN Clause -Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query to fetch and calculate the values accordingly. To fetch the value i am passing values in IN clause as below,

```
SELECT *
FROM SQ_HANDLING_TIME_T
WHERE QSC_CODE   = '001'
AND BU_TYPE_RULE = 'STO'
AND DEV_TYPE     = 'NC'
AND FIELD_NAME IN('NC_LQ2_PER_PALLET','NC_LQ2_PER_BOX','NC_LQ2_PER_APPLIANCES');
```

But it gives me records as perbox,perpallet and then per appliance data.
Its not coming in the same order as in In clause.
Is there any way in Oracle where i can get records in same order as in In clause.

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: The wehere clause is only a filter it will not be sorted

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339589/custom-order-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure; apply `ORDER BY` clause which takes care about order in the `WHERE` clause. Here's an example based on Scott's schema:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename, job, sal
  2  from emp
  3  where job in ('MANAGER', 'CLERK', 'SALESMAN')
  4  order by decode(job, 'MANAGER', 1, 'CLERK', 2, 'SALESMAN', 3);

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
        20 JONES      MANAGER         2975
        30 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
        30 JAMES      CLERK            950
        20 SMITH      CLERK            800
        10 MILLER     CLERK           1300
        30 TURNER     SALESMAN        1500
        30 WARD       SALESMAN        1250
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
        30 MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

In your case, that would be

```
...
ORDER BY DECODE(field_name, 'NC_LQ2_PER_PALLET', 1,
                            'NC_LQ2_PER_BOX', 2,
                            'NC_LQ2_PER_APPLIANCES', 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM SQ_HANDLING_TIME_T
WHERE QSC_CODE     = '001'
  AND BU_TYPE_RULE = 'STO'
  AND DEV_TYPE     = 'NC'
  AND FIELD_NAME IN ('NC_LQ2_PER_PALLET','NC_LQ2_PER_BOX', 
                     'NC_LQ2_PER_APPLIANCES');
ORDER BY
    CASE FIELD_NAME
        WHEN 'NC_LQ2_PER_PALLET'     THEN 1
        WHEN 'NC_LQ2_PER_BOX'        THEN 2
        WHEN 'NC_LQ2_PER_APPLIANCES' THEN 3
    END;
```

Comment: Littlefoots answer is just fine.  It can also be done as a case instead of a decode.