# Select record in a specific order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below..

```
Select name from t1;
```

Op:

```
 name
 ----
 A
 D
 X
 Z
```

Want op like below

```
 Name
-----
X
A
D
Z
```

**Without using union operator**
Should be a single query

Comment: What if there are other values than `A, D, X, Z`, in which order would you display them?

Comment: Just curious; was it an interview question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Order in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339589/custom-order-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just those values:

```
SELECT name FROM t1
ORDER BY
  case name when 'X' then 0 else 1 end,
  name
```

X is the only one that is out of alphabetical order so if we use a case to assign 0 to that and 1 to everything else, and sort by 0/1 first, then we will end up with X sorted first and everything else tied on 1. The tie is resolved by then sorting alphabetically on name after we sort on the CASE

There are other similar tricks you can pull using decode, case when to give everything a value (like gmb did), replacing X with null and sorting NULLS FIRST, replacing X with something that will sort before A such as 0...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a *fixed* conditional ordering, like so?

```
select name
from t1
order by
    case name
        when 'X' then 1
        when 'A' then 2
        when 'D' then 3
        when 'Z' then 4
        else 5
    end,
    name
```