# Select Table records in given order - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-order-by

I have table lets say - Students, with 5 records and id(s) are 1 to 5, now i want to select the records - in a way that result should come like given sorting order of id column

id column should be resulted - 5,2,1,3,4 ( order may vary each time)

is there any other way to do this in oracle sql?

In mysql we have FIELD() clause to do this. I want to achieve this in oracle.

Comment: If you sort by id it will sort in order.  On which field do you want to sort?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Order in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339589/custom-order-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle uses **heap-oraganized table**, which means by default rows are stored in no particular order. However, while selecting the rows, you could mention **ORDER BY** clause explicitly to return the result set in ASC(default)/DESC order.

You could use DECODE/CASE to customize the sorting, for example:

```
with data as(
select level num from dual connect by level <=5 
)
select num
from data 
order by case 
 when num = 5 then 1
 when num = 2 then 2
 when num = 1 then 3 
 when num = 3 then 4 
 when num = 4 then 5
end;

       NUM
----------
         5
         2
         1
         3
         4
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way uses `instr()`:

```
order by instr(',5,2,1,3,4,', ',' || id ',')
```

To handle values not in the string, you can convert them to `NULL` and sort those accordingly:

```
order by nullif(instr(',5,2,1,3,4,', ',' || id ','), 0) nulls last
```