# how to order result data as I put in where 'IN' in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, sql-order-by

I put search condition in where 'IN'() and want it to display in order as it is the 'IN' in oracle.

the data in 'IN'() is the data of LOGIN_ID field, which is unique and consists of string type.

so, for example, the query would be like below,

```
select login_id from table where login_id in ('1234', 'abcd', '12cd')';
```

and the result has to be shown as like this,

```
=======
login_id
=======
'1234'
'abcd'
'12cd'
```

example of wrong result is like this,

```
=======
login_id
=======
'abcd'
'12cd'
'1234'
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Order in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339589/custom-order-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't preserve the order of an IN-list, but you can use a very similar syntax with a built-in collection and the `TABLE` operator to convert the values to rows and then order by them. The below query is weird, but it avoids having to change the list of values expression into a large `CASE` statement or something else.

```
select some_table.login_id
from some_table
join
(
    select column_value login_id, rownum order_number
    from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('1234', 'abcd', '12cd'))
) in_list
    on some_table.login_id = in_list.login_id
order by order_number;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific Oracle feature for that.

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select login_id 
from table 
where login_id in ('1234', 'abcd', '12cd')
order by case login_id
    when '1234' then 1
    when 'abcd' then 2
    when '12cd' then 3
end
```

`decode()` can shorter the syntax a little:

```
order by decode(login_id, '1234', 1, 'abcd', 2, '12cd', 3)
```

Comment: there are a lot of data in 'IN' like 400 row data. so I wouldn't put 'then n' along every when case..

Comment: It seems that you will, if you want to get result you mentioned. `IN` can be switched to a subquery where all those values are stored in some table. As in relational database rows aren't sorted in any particular way, you have to use ORDER BY clause to sort them. If there's algorithm that is capable of doing that, use it. Otherwise, there's no way to say that 1234 goes first, abcd second and 12cd third.