# Multiple Custom orders oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-order-by

Is it possible to perform sn `ORDER BY` in Oracle SQL that is driven by multiple orders for while using the `CASE`?

For example:

```
+------------------+
| Code | DateTime  |
+------------------+
| ABC  | 7-01-2020 |
+------------------+
| DSF  | 7-01-2020 |
+------------------+
| ABC  | 6-01-2020 |
+------------------+
```

I would want to order this where the `Code` is `ABC` and then order it by the `DateTime` of the row.
Why can't I do this?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN CODE = 'ABC' THEN '001'
        ELSE 'ZZZ'
    END
AND DATETIME ASC;
```

I am only able to use the `CASE` statement and nothing else in the `ORDER BY` clause. If I remove the `AND DATETIME ASC;` the query will complete with only ordering by the `CODE` where the code `ABC` is first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by multiple terms if you separate them by a comma (`,`), not an `AND`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN CODE = 'ABC' THEN '001'
        ELSE 'ZZZ'
    END, -- Note the comma here
    DATETIME ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would not use strings for the `case` expression:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN CODE = 'ABC' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         DATETIME ASC;
```

Strings work, of course.  They just look awkward.

Comment: Wouldn't using characters imply that the order is by alphabetical order for everything else? I took it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339589/custom-order-in-oracle-sql

Comment: @Jimenemex . . . The first example uses numbers.  Strings are only used to be compatible with another type (in that case, `currency`).